# adapt radio datatable primefaces to my case jsf2

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces, radio-button

I want to use this radio datatable:
[here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf)

but I want to trigger the dialog without clicking on view button ,

here is my xhtml page :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">  

            <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{newJSFManagedBean.mediumPapiersModel}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
                         selection="#{newJSFManagedBean.selectedPapier}"  >  

                <f:facet name="header">  
                    RadioButton Based Selection  
                </f:facet>  

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{newJSFManagedBean.onRowSelect}"   
                    update=":form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" />  

                <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:18px" />  

                 <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{newJSFManagedBean.onRowSelect}"   
                    update=":form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" /> 

                <p:column headerText="libelle">  
                    #{car.libelle}  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column headerText="format">  
                    #{car.format}  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column headerText="stock" >  
                    #{car.stock}  
                </p:column>  


            </p:dataTable>  

            <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"  
                      showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">  

                <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  

                     <h:outputText value="id" />  
                     <h:outputText value="#{newJSFManagedBean.selectedPapier.id}" />  

                    <h:outputText value="format" />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{newJSFManagedBean.selectedPapier.format}" />  

                    <h:outputText value="grammage" />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{newJSFManagedBean.selectedPapier.grammage}" />  

                    <h:outputText value="libelle" />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{newJSFManagedBean.selectedPapier.libelle}" />  
                </h:panelGrid>  
            </p:dialog>  

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and here is my managedBean :

```
package controlleurs.admin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import pojos_mappingFiles.Papier;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class NewJSFManagedBean {

    metiers.admin.stockHelper sh;
    Papier selectedPapier;  
    List<Papier> papiers;
    papierDataModel mediumPapiersModel;
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of NewJSFManagedBean
     */
    public NewJSFManagedBean() {
        sh = new metiers.admin.stockHelper();
        papiers = new ArrayList<Papier>();
        papiers = sh.getPapiers();
        for(Papier pap : papiers ){
            pap.setChecked(false);
        }
        mediumPapiersModel = new papierDataModel(papiers);
    }

    public Papier getSelectedPapier() {
        System.out.println("j ai selectionz ");
        return selectedPapier;
    }

    public void setSelectedPapier(Papier selectedPapier) {
        System.out.println("je suis selectionné mon numero : "+selectedPapier.getLibelle());
        this.selectedPapier = selectedPapier;
    }

    public papierDataModel getMediumPapiersModel() {
        return mediumPapiersModel;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
        System.out.println("je suis dans onRowSelect");  
    } 

}
```

and here is the papierDataModel :

```
package controlleurs.admin;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;   
import org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel;  
import pojos_mappingFiles.Papier;


public class papierDataModel extends ListDataModel<Papier> implements SelectableDataModel<Papier> {

    public papierDataModel() {  
    }  

    public papierDataModel(List<Papier> data) {  
        super(data);  
    }  

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Papier t) {
        return t.getId().toString();

    }

    @Override
    public Papier getRowData(String rowKey) {
        List<Papier> papiers = (List<Papier>) getWrappedData();  

        for(Papier car : papiers) {  
            if(car.getId().toString().equals(rowKey))  
                return car;  
        }  

        return null;  
    }

}
```

but the dialog doesn't appear when I check one of row , I don't know the cause, do you have any idea , thanks

Comment: try to place `<p:dialog id="dialog"` outside that form and place another form inside the dialog and try again... or you can try adding `appendToBody=true` to your current dialog , b.t.w dont use `:` in ids when its in the same form , instead of `update=":form:display"` use `update="display"`

Comment: Are you sure you need the `SelectEvent` Parameter on the `public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event)` method?
Looking at the show case the listener methods on the beans are empty resp. have no parameter at all.

Comment: I removed the selectEvent parameter and I added the appendtobody attrbute but again no result

Comment: You need to debug this in javascript mode using your browser's developer/javascript console. Turn this on in your browser and see what the error console is printing. You might also want to check the network tab of the console to ensure that the rowSelect event is indeed firing.

Comment: Remove the fancy jquery effects just to be safe, include the rowKey attribute. p.s. you don't need the checkbox, if all you need is selection and dialog display, just use plain `<p:ajax/>` based selection. It works, i've tested it before commenting here.